# Get claims in ASP.NET MVC 5 client, set for TestUser in Identity Server 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have my Client added to the IdentityServer4 identity provider app.

```
     new Client
        {
            ClientId = "mvc4Simple",
            ClientName = "MVC 4 Web Client",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
            RequireConsent = false,
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },
            AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken=true,
            AlwaysSendClientClaims=true,
            RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44347/signin-oidc" },
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44347/signout-callback-oidc" },
            AllowedScopes = new List<string>
             {
              IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
              IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
              IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email                 
             },
             AllowOfflineAccess = true,
             RequirePkce = false,
             AllowPlainTextPkce = false
        }
```

And IdentityResources like that

```
     public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
        {
         new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
         new IdentityResources.Profile(),
         new IdentityResources.Email()
        };
    }
```

And my TestUser like that

```
  new TestUser
  {
      SubjectId = "12345678",
      Username = "John",
      Password = "12345",
      Claims = new List<Claim> {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "xyz@gmail.com"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin")
            }
  }
```

And my client is a simple asp.net MVC application. The client configuration is like that

```
    [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MVCSimple.Startup))]
    namespace MVCSimple
    {
       public partial class Startup
       {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
         {
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap =
            new Dictionary<string, string>();            
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
              AuthenticationType = "cookie"
            });          
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
             AuthenticationType = "oidc",           
             Authority = "https://localhost:44316",
             ClientId = "mvc4Simple",
             ClientSecret = "secret",
             ResponseType = "code id_token",
             Scope = "openid profile",
             UseTokenLifetime = false,
             RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44347/signin-oidc",
             PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44347/signout-callback-oidc",                 
             SignInAsAuthenticationType = "cookie",
             Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
             {
                SecurityTokenValidated = context =>
                        {                             
                        context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new 
                          Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, context.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },

                RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == 
                     Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                    {
                        var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                        if (idTokenHint != null)
                        {
                            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                        }

                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
              }
           });
         }
       }
     }
```

Authentication works fine. It redirects me back to my application but I want to know how can I get the claims set for my TestUser i.e Email and Role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read some articles about it. And got it resolved.
I had to add one scope.

```
     new ApiScope("api1.read", "Read Access to API #1")
         {
           UserClaims={
                ClaimTypes.Email,
                ClaimTypes.Role
                }
         }
```

Then change the client details

```
    new Client
    {
        ClientId = "mvc4Simple",
        ClientName = "MVC 4 Web Client",
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
        AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
        RequireConsent = false,
        ClientSecrets =
        {
            new Secret("secret".Sha256())
        },
        AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken=true,
        AlwaysSendClientClaims=true,
        RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44347/signin-oidc" },
        PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44347/signout-callback-oidc" },
        AllowedScopes = new List<string>
         {
          IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
          IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
          IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email 
          "api1.read"                
         },
         AllowOfflineAccess = true,
         RequirePkce = false,
         AllowPlainTextPkce = false
    }
```

Then in the Startup class added token as the response type.

```
     public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
     {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap =
        new Dictionary<string, string>();            
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
          AuthenticationType = "cookie"
        });          
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
         AuthenticationType = "oidc",           
         Authority = "https://localhost:44316",
         ClientId = "mvc4Simple",
         ClientSecret = "secret",
         ResponseType = "code id_token token",
         Scope = "openid profile api1.read",//Include that scope here
         UseTokenLifetime = false,
         RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44347/signin-oidc",
         PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44347/signout-callback-oidc",                 
         SignInAsAuthenticationType = "cookie",
         SaveTokens=true,
         Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
         {
            SecurityTokenValidated = context =>
                    {                             
                    context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new 
                    Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,context.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
              context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", 
       context.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));//Set access token in access_token claim
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },

            RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
            {
                if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType ==                    
      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                {
             var idTokenHint =n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");
                    if (idTokenHint != null)
                    {
                        n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                    }

                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
          }
       });
     }
```

And finally, I was able to get those claims in my controller's action method as follows

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;     
        var token= identity.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "access_token").ToList();
        if (token.Count > 0) 
        {
            var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken(token[0].Value);
            var claimsjwt=jwtToken.Claims;//Here you can get all the claims set for the user i.e email , role
        }
        return View();
    }
```